# How to use cURL POST to create Firebase Firestore document in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0

Novice in WordPress here.

- I want to create new Firebase Firestore documents through cURL POST operations in a WordPress page
- I don't want to install any existing Firebase plugins or modify any .php files in my WP theme (i.e. localize all Firestore-related code inside a single WP page)

Currently, I need to pass in an OAuth 2.0 token that was generated using a Google service account's private key. However, I couldn't find any resources that showed me how to achieve this from within a WordPress page.

Using PHP, here is the code I have written:

```php
<?php
$firestore_data  = [
  "testField1" => ["stringValue" => "One"],
  "testField2" => ["integerValue" =>2],
];
$data = ["fields" => (object)$firestore_data];

$json = json_encode($data);
// Enter your firestore unique key: below is a sample
$url = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectnamehere/databases/(default)/documents/collectionidhere/testdocumenthere';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
      'Authorization: Bearer OAuthTokenHere',
      'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PATCH'),
  CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?key=WebAPIKeyHere',
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'cURL',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));

$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

// Show result
echo $response;
?>
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
“error”: {
   “code”: 403,
   “message”: “Missing or insufficient permissions.”,
   “status”: “PERMISSION_DENIED”
}
```

So:

1. Is generating an OAuth access token from within a WordPress website possible?
2. If so, can it be achieved in a WordPress page?